# Restore database on other computer needs to create a master key

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I am making a backup and then restore it on another computer, I am getting the error

> please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. First of all, is the problem in backup or restore routine? Or in my action when trying to open symmetric key?
I can post any example of my code you ask for. Here is my backup routine:

```
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {

      using (SqlConnection connetion = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString))
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE [" + Connection.Database + "] TO  DISK = '" + dlg.SelectedPath + "\\myBackup.bak'", connetion))
      {
        connetion.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
}
```

Also i tried to delete my symmetric key after restore but it doesnt remove it.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE [" + Connection.Database + "] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", connection))
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE [" + Connection.Database + "] FROM DISK = '" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "' WITH REPLACE", connection))
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.certificates WHERE name = 'PasswordEncryption') select 1 else select 0", connection))
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1)
                        {

                            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER DROP SYMMETRIC KEY Customer_Password;", connection))
                                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();



                        }


                }
```

Comment: Do you need to restore and backup master key?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-master-key-transact-sql   and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-master-key-transact-sql

Comment: I dont want to make double job. I dont want to create 2 backups, one database and another the master key.  If it is possible to delete master key on restore and recreate it. Or even better to recreate my encryption password key

Comment: Your getting that error on the restore operation? Or some other operation that you're performing post-restore?

Comment: No, just when i try to open symmetric key i am getting error.